# Registering Device Instance on Google Assistant SDK - Error 400

Tags: python-3.x, google-assistant-sdk

I've been trying to register a device instance on Google Assistant SDK on my Raspberry Pi 3.

Here is my input code

```
googlesamples-assistant-devicetool --project-id RASPI-ED53D register --model RASPI-ED53D-LIGHT-7NBZNA --type OUTLET --manufacturer SUPERCONN --product-name LIGHT --device 0001 --client-type LIBRARY
```

Output/Error

Creating new device model
Error: Failed to register model: 400

Could not create the device model. Check that the request contains the required field project_id with a valid format in the request payload. See https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/device-registration/model-and-instance-schemas for more information.

The syntax is correct according to the google resources.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The schema lists `action.devices.types.OUTLET`, not `OUTLET`.
When I list my devices, they have similar types specified, e.g.:
`Device Type: action.devices.types.SPEAKER`